# Do the individual builders listed in Nehemiah 3 represent larger household groups?

Tags: nehemiah, family

Nehemiah 3 lists the builders who were responsible for repairing different parts of Jerusalem's wall. Sometimes the text makes explicit reference to a group of builders, e.g.:

> Eliashib the high priest rose up **with his brothers** the priests, and **they built**...

(verse 1)

> The sons of Hassenaah built...

(verse 3)

However, several individual builders are listed as responsible for the wall. E.g.:

> And next to them **Meremoth the son of Uriah**, son of Hakkoz repaired. And next to them **Meshullam the son of Berechiah**, son of Meshezabel repaired. And next to them **Zadok the son of Baana** repaired.

(verse 4)

Where individual builders are listed in this way, are we to infer that these family-heads oversaw the work of their families and servants on that portion of the wall, or does the text describe the stoic efforts of one man working unassisted on the portion of the wall for which he is responsible?

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred that there were no chapter division between Neh 3 and Neh 4 as it is a single narrative.  Let us observe several things about this story.

Most of the people that worked on the building project did so in small family teams.  For example

- Neh 3:1 - were a group of priests
- Neh 3:2 - the residents of Jericho
- Neh 3:3 - "the sons of Hassenaah"
- Neh 3:4, 5 - small sections repaired by a single man in each case
- Neh 3:6 - two men working together
- Neh 3:7 - men of Gibeon and men of Mizpah
- Neh 3:8 - two men restored two smaller sections
- .
- Neh 3:13 - a larger section (1000 cubits) of wall restored by Hanun and the whole town of Zanoah
- .
- Neh 3:22 - repairs to a large section made by priests of the surrounding area
- Neh 3:23 - repairs made to the wall opposite the house of Bejamin and Hassub

... and so forth.  That is, some teams were large, ie, the residents of a whole village; and some were much smaller - just one man working on a small section opposite his house.  In all, there appears to be perhaps several thousand people who worked on various sections of the wall.

Note the record in Neh 4:16-18 -

> And from that day on, half of my servants did the work while the other
> half held spears, shields, bows, and armor. The officers stationed
> themselves behind all the people of Judah who were rebuilding the
> wall. The laborers who carried materials worked with one hand and held
> a weapon with the other. And each of the builders worked with his
> sword strapped at his side. But the trumpeter stayed beside me.

Thus, the work proceeded with a very large group of people.  Note further the record in Neh 4:21-23 -

> So we continued the work, while half of the men held spears from the
> break of dawn until the stars came out. At that time I also said to
> the people, “Let every man and his servant spend the night inside
> Jerusalem, so that they can stand guard by night and work by day.” So
> neither I nor my brothers nor my servants nor the guards with me
> changed out of our clothes; each carried his weapon, even to go for
> water.

Note again, that every man had a helper and so the several thousand people working in the wall probably each had a helper as well.  Neh 6:15 - "the wall was completed ... in 52 days" - a significant effort by a very large team of people!

Answer (score 0):

Nehemiah 3:

> 3The Fish Gate was rebuilt by the sons of Hassenaah. They laid its beams and put its doors and bolts and bars in place.

That's not the work of just one man.

> 4 **Meremoth** son of Uriah, the son of Hakkoz, repaired the next section. Next to him Meshullam son of Berekiah, the son of Meshezabel, made repairs, and next to him Zadok son of Baana also made repairs. 5The next section was repaired by the men of Tekoa, but their nobles would not put their shoulders to the work under their supervisors.

Again, group effort was needed to repair a section.

> 9 Rephaiah son of Hur, ruler of a half-district of Jerusalem, repaired the next section.

Now, I start to assume that Rephaiah didn't do it alone by himself to repair this section of the wall.

> 12 Shallum son of Hallohesh, ruler of a half-district of Jerusalem, repaired the next section with the help of his daughters.

It does not explicitly mention the sons. I assume that they had help if he had any sons.

> 21
> Next to him, **Meremoth** son of Uriah, the son of Hakkoz, repaired another section, from the entrance of Eliashib’s house to the end of it.

This same Meremoth was back to repair another section, along with his sons. I think it would have been a disgrace to Meremoth if his sons didn't help him.

Do the individual builders listed in Nehemiah 3 represent larger household groups?

Each name represents at least his own household with his sons, not just him.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for this answer. I'm not sure there's sufficient evidence here to back it up? Are you assuming that individuals represent groups because in other places groups are required to repair a section?

Comment: Good point. I tried to show that the individual represented him and his sons. I added to my answer.